# Camel - json body is consumed after have used jsonpath

Tags: json, apache-camel, jsonpath

i'm using camel in a rest context and i've to manipulate a json got from a request . It's something like:

```
{
 'field1':'abc',
 'field2':'def'
}
```

All i've to do is to extract field1 and field2 and put them in 2 properties, so i tried something like that

```
<setProperty propertyName="Field1">
  <jsonpath>$.field1</jsonpath>
</setProperty>
<setProperty propertyName="Field2">
  <jsonpath>$.field2</jsonpath>
</setProperty>
```

but i get this error:
`org.apache.camel.ExpressionEvaluationException: 
com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object with property ['field2'] in path $ but found 'java.lang.String'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.`

and after some tests i found out my body was empty after the first use of jsonpath.

The same process applied to an XML using xpath doesn't give any error, and i'm wondering if it's possible to do the same with jsonpath instead to create a mapper object in java. thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the processed Camel message is of type InputStream, this stream can obviously be read only once.

To solve this:

- either enable Camel stream caching (http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html)
- or insert a step (before jsonpath queries) in your route to convert message body to a string (so that it can be read multiple times: 
  (eg `<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" charset="ISO-8859-1">`) )